# android proguard, custom views and project rebuild

Tags: android, package, proguard, custom-view

I have a pretty big application that I'm trying to obfuscate with ProGuard. It uses android support library, FragmentActivities, and has a lot of Compound Views that extend either View, RelativeLayout or FrameLayout.

The problem is ProGuard fails to keep some of the views (and afterwards I get `ClassNotFoundException` as they are referenced in the XML) Interestingly, those missing views belong to one specific package (my views are spread over 3 or 4 different packages). I am not able to get those views preserved, even by writing explicit rules.

**UPDATE**

It turns out to be very related to how I clean/rebuild the project etc.

In my experience so far, the only way to get the signed apk correctly including all classes is doing:

1. Disable Automatic Project Building
2. Clean all projects (Manually)
3. Manually build the project, and
4. Generate the signed APK

If I enable auto-building, or not clean the project between builds, the resulting APK has random missing classes.

I wonder if I am doing anything wrong, or if you guys have this problem or a solution for it. Also any tricks regarding proguard cleaning, etc are more than welcome! thanks in advance.

**OLD QUESTION**

My package hierarchy:

```
Application: tv.nebular.funq
Views 1:  tv.nebular.funq.gui.*
Views 2:  tv.nebular.funq.apps.*
Views 3:  com.regaliz.gui.views.*
Views 4:  com.regaliz.custom.*
```

The views in packages (3) and (4) are the ones I'm having problem with. Even though the packages are different, they are not different projects. It's a single project.

My rules regarding views:

```
    -keep public class * extends android.view.View {
        public <init>(android.content.Context);
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
        public void set*(...);
    }

    -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    }

    -keepclasseswithmembers class * {
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    }
```

And the specific rules for the missing Views:

```
    # regaliz views

    -keep public class com.regaliz.gui.views.*

    -keepclassmembers class com.regaliz.gui.views.** { 
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    }

    # regaliz custom

    -keep public class com.regaliz.custom.FunqViewPager

    -keepclassmembers class com.regaliz.custom.FunqViewPager { 
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    }
```

However, this seems to be ignored. Views in those packages are always missing. Even the one declared explicitly.

**UPDATE:**
Looking at proguard-mapping.txt output file, I see the views should have been correctly kept, but the fact is, they are missing!

Any help appreciated!

Comment: it would help if you include the exact runtime error.

Comment: it's a plain classnotfound, I've modified the question, thanks!

Comment: I've run into this occasionally and it is often resolved by cleaning your project (and any related library projects) and rebuilding.

Comment: Cleaning the project shed some light over what's happening, I've narrowed the problem to some views being obfuscated, and trying to write rules to avoid it. Thanks for the tip.